# Spring Hibernate JPA @Transaction(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) can't find object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm asking this question after 5 hours staring at the monitor

I have code with the following format

```
@Transaction(readmode=true)
class SomeServiceClass {
    @Autowired
    SubServiceClassA subServiceClassA;

    @Autowired
    SubServiceClassB subServiceClassB;

    public void doSomething() {
        Long id = subServiceClassA.performSave();

        subServiceClassB.performAction(id);
    }
}
```

I persist an object and return the id.

```
@Service
class SubServiceClassA {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Long performSave() {
        SomeObj someObj = someRepository.save(SomeObj someObj);
        return someObj.getId();
    }
}
```

Later in a separate `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction, I attempt to do something with the newly saved object.

```
@Service
class SubServiceClassB {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void performAction(Long id) {
        SomeObj someObj = someRepository.find(id);
        // someObj is null here!!! :(
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that this code should work, since the object saved was in a `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction in a separate bean.

My problem is that this code works great in my local setting. When I upload this to production setting, I get a NPE because `someObj` is `null`. (We are using gradle, so dependencies should be the same)

I would appreciate it greatly if I can get any pointers as to why this may not work.

Comment: Is the insert query fired after the code exit the SubServiceClassA .performSave() method?

Comment: The insert code is `someRepository.save(SomeObj someObj);`. It's inside the `SubServiceClassA. performSave()` method

Comment: try to call subServiceClassB.performAction(id) from another method. What is the purpose of `@Transaction(readmode=true)`

Comment: `SomeServiceClass` has other methods besides `doSomething` which requires `@Transactional`. Is there a reason why `subServiceClassB.performAction(id) ` should be in a different method? It should be in a new transaction anyways...

Comment: what i meant was: is the actual SQL query fired when exiting the performSave()? trying to understand if the transaction is actually committed or not to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

I guess I was posting without extra info

The code in my ServiceB class was

```
@Service
class SubServiceClassB {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readonly=true)
    public void performAction(Long id) {
        SomeObj someObj = someRepository.find(id);
        // someObj is null here!!! :(
    }
}
```

The problem was that I was writing an object in ServiceA to the master DB, but reading from a slave DB. Apparently, setting `readonly=true` forced the server to read from a slaveDB, however the newly persisted object hadn't been replicated to the slave DB yet.

After removing the `readonly=true`, everything worked fine.